# Lotus Notes Embedded View - Indicate where the users is in the hierarchy

Tags: lotus-notes

I am working on a legacy Lotus Notes application. The app has many response and response-to-response documents. The user would like an embedded view that highlights or somehow indicates where the user is in the hierarchy. This is common on the web, and I bet I can do it in Xpages, but can it been done in LN?. Could I construct an embedded view that uses HTML to do this, or a field that uses HTML?

I was not clear in my original question. What I meant by where the user was in the heirarchy was just which comment they were looking at in the list of comments. So there is a project document, and there can be comments on this project document, and comments on a comment, and so on. We might have 50 comments, and some of the comments have comments. The problem is that when a user is looking at a particular comment document, they do not know where they are in the list of comments.

Comment: Think about breadcrumbs (navigate up) with embedded view with immediate descendants (navigate down).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one document per employee and that each document contains the Employee ID of the employee's direct supervisor, you could do this in an embedded view using cascading categories.  But you would need to code an agent to calculate a new field containing the employee's entire chain of command in "Name + Employee Id / Name + Employee Id / Name + Employee Id... etc" format.  The names would be in order from top of the hierarchy down to the employee.  The IDs would be necessary for uniqueness.  Your view would be categorized on this new field.  (You may need another view sorted by Employee ID for your agent to use for lookups while building this field, if you don't have one already.)

This would be pretty ugly, though, and I don't see any way to limit the embedded view to just showing the documents in the employee's hierarchy. I don't believe that the show single category feature will do what you want, because what you actually have is a cascade of categories and sub-categories.

A field that uses HTML is certainly possible, though. In this case, your agent will have to walk the hierarchy and construct the links correctly.  It could even be done without an agent, just using a looping construct in formula language -- but hierarchy doesn't change that often and it would be wasteful (and maybe a bit slow) to have to calculate it every time a use looks at a document, so I'd probably stick with the agent approach and tell people that they might have to wait until the next agent run before they see any changes reflected on their screen.